# Daemon and gui app accessing same data files

Tags: permissions, root, gui, daemon

I have a daemon that needs access to (read/write) some files that a gui app also has access to (read/write).  The daemon runs as root but the gui does not.  Each time the daemon accesses the files, the owner becomes root:root.  What is the preferred way to handle this?

This is in Ubuntu 16.04, doesn't need to be compatible with anything else.

is there also a best/preferred location to put these files?

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions:

- If the daemon doesn't need to be root, make it run as the user.
- Change the UFLAGs of the daemon so that the file is created `rw-rw-rw-`.
- Since the daemon is root, it can explicitly change the ownership of the file after it creates it.
- Make the daemon run in a specific-group common with the user where both have R/W access to the group files.
- Reconsider your design to avoid the situation.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't find a way to run app as non-root in systemd (new to systemd) but I guess I can use runuser, or something like that.

Comment: I now see the User= and Group= in the systemd unit file settings (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/systemd.exec.5.html).  I put them under the [service] banner